Pytorch Geometric_Random_Link_Split error
I'm working on a class project. We are trying to use Pytorch Geometric with GNN to detect money laundering in a IBM dataset on Kaggle. What we did was to create a Pytorch Geometric Data object with edge_index, edge_attr, and edge_label, then to split the data object into train, val, and test dataset. However, it seems that the dataset is not properly split. For example, the edge_label is plit, but the edge_index and edge_attr are not.
Additionally, another issue I have is that it keeps saying that the edge indexes are out of bound during training or validation. Sometimes, it works but not consistently. I'm not sure this is caused by the split. I try to create some manual random split as well, but the indexing issue still happens.
Please help! Thank you!
`# Convert to PyTorch tensors with correct dtypes
torch_edges_labels = torch.tensor(df.select("Is Laundering").collect(), dtype=torch.long).to(device)  # Changed to torch.long
torch_edges = torch.tensor(edges.collect(), dtype=torch.long).t().contiguous().to(device)
torch_edges_features = torch.tensor(df_features.collect(), dtype=torch.float).to(device)

# # Create PyTorch Geometric Data object
pyGData = Data(
    num_nodes=nodes.count(),
    edge_index=torch_edges,
    edge_attr=torch_edges_features,
    edge_label=torch_edges_labels
).to(device)

# Initialize split transform with proper settings
split = transforms.RandomLinkSplit(
    is_undirected=True,
    split_labels=False,
    num_val=0.2,
    num_test=0.2,
)

# Perform split with proper error handling
try:
    train_data, val_data, test_data = split(pyGData)`

edge_index, edge_attr, and edge_label in each train, val, and test dataset should be split properly.
Additionaly, this might help with the issue that the edge index is out of bound during training and evaluation.

Data Splitting
RandomLinkSplit is designed for link prediction tasks and can introduce complexities like negative sampling. RandomLinkSplit works by splitting edges into a subset for training and a subset for validation and finaly one for testing. It optionally has negative sampling. RandomSplitLink adjusts the edge_index in each split to include the edges assigned to the split, however, it does not handle edge_attr or custom _edge_label, if split_label=True, it will split labels accordingly. Try manually splitting the data into training, validation and test sets to ensure you split edge_index, edge_attr, and edge_label.
Example:
Manually split the components.
# Generate edge indices for splitting
num_edges = pyGData.edge_index.size(1)
edge_indices = torch.arange(num_edges)

# Convert tensors to numpy for sklearn
edge_indices_np = edge_indices.cpu().numpy()
edge_label_np = pyGData.edge_label.cpu().numpy()

# First split: Train vs Temp (Val + Test)
train_idx, temp_idx, y_train, y_temp = train_test_split(
    edge_indices_np,
    edge_label_np,
    test_size=0.4,  # 60% train, 40% temp
    random_state=42,
    stratify=edge_label_np
)

# Second split: Validation vs Test
val_size = 0.5  # Since temp is 40%, val and test each get 20%
val_idx, test_idx, y_val, y_test = train_test_split(
    temp_idx,
    y_temp,
    test_size=0.5,
    random_state=42,
    stratify=y_temp
)

# Convert back to tensors
train_idx = torch.tensor(train_idx, dtype=torch.long)
val_idx = torch.tensor(val_idx, dtype=torch.long)
test_idx = torch.tensor(test_idx, dtype=torch.long)

Split the edge_index, edge_attr and edge_label with obtained indices from above:
train_data = Data(
    num_nodes=num_nodes,
    edge_index=pyGData.edge_index[:, train_idx],
    edge_attr=pyGData.edge_attr[train_idx],
    edge_label=pyGData.edge_label[train_idx]
).to(device)

val_data = Data(
    num_nodes=num_nodes,
    edge_index=pyGData.edge_index[:, val_idx],
    edge_attr=pyGData.edge_attr[val_idx],
    edge_label=pyGData.edge_label[val_idx]
).to(device)

test_data = Data(
    num_nodes=num_nodes,
    edge_index=pyGData.edge_index[:, test_idx],
    edge_attr=pyGData.edge_attr[test_idx],
    edge_label=pyGData.edge_label[test_idx]
).to(device)

Even if you disable negative sampling (add_negative_train_samples=False, etc.), RandomLinkSplit inherently removes edges from the training set and assigns them to validaiton and test sets.
RandomLinkSplit can still be used but manually splitting edge_attr to match would be required so manually is preferred.
Re-Indexing
In the case of re-indexing the nodes the problem is likely that the node indices in edge_index may refer to nodes that are not present in the train, validation, or test sets after the split.
To fix:
-Map old indices to new, contiguous node indices for each dataset (train, validaiton and test). Apply this mapping.
Example:
def reindex_nodes(data):
    unique_nodes = torch.unique(data.edge_index.flatten())
    # Mapping from old node indices to new ones
    node_mapping = {node.item(): i for i, node in enumerate(unique_nodes)}

    # Apply mapping to edge indices
    row, col = data.edge_index
    mapped_row = row.apply_(lambda x: node_mapping[x])
    mapped_col = col.apply_(lambda x: node_mapping[x])
    data.edge_index = torch.stack([mapped_row, mapped_col], dim=0)

    data.num_nodes = unique_nodes.size(0)

    return data

# Apply the function to each dataset
train_data = reindex_nodes(train_data)
val_data = reindex_nodes(val_data)
test_data = reindex_nodes(test_data)


Hi, thanks so much for the support! It works. The data splits nicely.
The next issue that I encountered was during training or validation, the indices of the edge_index are larger than the valid indices (I assume the node indices). I have tried various method to reindex and remap the edge_index to the new node indices of the split datasets, but did not work. Do you have a suggestion for this?

@Mahana I have edited the post to include a potential solution the the indexing problem.

Hi! The mapping works. However, it does not solve the problem. The error is still like below.
"f (index.numel() > 0 and index.max() >= src.size(self.node_dim)):
--> 282                 raise IndexError(
283                     f"Found indices in 'edge_index' that are larger "
284                     f"than {src.size(self.node_dim) - 1} (got "
Found indices in 'edge_index' that are larger than 29999 (got 33325)"
Using a sample dataframe, the edge_index has the shape [2,30000], but the max index is 33325.
Is there a way to adjust the node_dim manually?
